# Ember.js - Run view related JS on all transitions and not just when the model changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ember.js

I have a `"veteran"` model with a copy attribute, this is a filename which represents a HTML page that is loaded via AJAX on the profile page. The HTML file contains some hardcoded ember links, e.g `<a href="index.html#/veteran/1">Vet</a>`. The majority of these links work when transitioning to other models, but when the model is the same, the below ajax function isn't called, and the HTML file isn't loaded into the DOM.

How can I make sure this code is run on every transition, instead of just when the model changes?

```
 App.VeteranView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        // Here we fetch the URL provided in the veteran model and load this data, which represents the main copy
        // of the particular vet into the attr div
        Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function(){
            var ember = this.$().attr('id');
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var div = $('#' + ember).find(".attr");
                var url = div.data("id");
                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    div.html(data);
                    if ($(window).width() >= 767) {
                        $('.profile-info .columnizer').columnize({ columns: 2 });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks to kingpin I managed to tweak his code, so that I can access dynamic DOM elements after every transition, even when the template stays the same. Setting the Ember run loop to "later" means that there's a 500ms delay, which seems to be enough time for everything to finish loading and transitioning.

```
App.VeteranView = Ember.View.extend({
watch: function(){
    Ember.run.later(this, this.ajaxLoad);
}.observes("controller"),

ajaxLoad: function(){
    // Here we fetch the URL provided in the veteran model
    // load this data, which represents the main copy
    // of the particular vet into the attr div
    var profileDiv = $(".profile-info");
    var url = profileDiv.find(".copy-url").text();
    if (url) {
        console.log("Rendering: " + url);
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            // First we'll load the data into the DOM
            profileDiv.find(".attr").html(data);

            // Now check if IE and browser width
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if ($(window).width() >= 767 && msie > 0) {
                profileDiv.find('.columnizer').columnize({ columns: 2 });
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

});

Comment: A couple notes:  `$(document).ready` is probably only triggered on page load.  Am I wrong?  Also, you grab the id from an element (`var ember = this.$().attr('id');`) then use that id to grab the same element (`$('#' + ember)`).  Another thing, the `didInsertElement` should be triggered only once on the view when its inserted. Perhaps put the AJAX in another method that you call manually.  Finally, you mention having a `veteran` model.  If you're using ember data, perhaps use the `store.find('veteran')` syntax to make a request.      Is any of this helpful?

Comment: document ready triggers immediately if the page is already ready, so there is no harm in it. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pidigufa/1/edit, it's pointless in this case, because the ember app doesn't start until the document is ready, but harmless all the same.

Comment: Hi Jim, all pointers are welcome thank you, I just think didInsertElement within the view object is the wrong approach to hook into every transition.

Comment: Do you mean that if you are on route 'a' and click a link to route 'a' the Ajax isn't called?

Comment: Hi Charlie, not quite. It's when you visit a page which shares the same underlying model, e.g. say I'm on "index#/veterans/1" and I go to "index#veterans/2" didInsertElement isn't called and the AJAX isn't executed. It's only called when the model changes, and this works just fine. I just want to hook into every transition, but when the DOM has loaded.

Comment: So really it's not sharing the same model, but the same view/template.

Comment: yes template rather than model thats correct.

Comment: So mine is removed when they switch out the particular view for the other view, but then the new one goes on model changed.  Does it only fire the once and it's empty?

Comment: Yes, the observer only seems to fire once the template has changed, and not on every transition leaving the this.$() always empty after the initial load.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

### 1. Do it in `setupController` it's executed each time the model changes.  Generally this isn't recommended for view magic, for that skip this option.

#### Setup Controller

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function(){
      alert('do it here');
    });
  }
});
```

### 2. Add an observers on the model reference, and when it changes go wild

#### View observing model

```
App.VeteranView = Ember.View.extend({
    watchStuff: function(){
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.doStuff);
    }.observes('controller.model').on('didInsertElement'),

    doStuff: function(){
      var el = this.$();
      if(el){
        el.hide(); // hahaha, get that user good
      }
    }
});
```

Example (check out the color view): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/674/edit

Comment: Hi Kingpin2k, this definitely seems close thank you, although I get undefined errors when trying to access DOM elements, such as this.$(). Ive updated the original question code.